# Upload file error message not appearing. CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I hope someone can help me with this. Whenever I upload a file with the wrong format and submit the form, an error is supposed to appear. However after passing multiple variables back to the view from my controller, none of the errors seem to be appearing. Thank you.

Controller Code :

```
function upload()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    //the name on the view must be userfile
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $company = $this->session->userdata('company');
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $description =$this->input->post('description');
    $path = './assets/files/'.$company.'/announcements';
    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size']    = '10000';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);


    $this->load->model('announcement');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['per_page']=5;
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {

        //$error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
        $data = array(
        'announcement' => $this->announcement->fetch_announcement($username,$company,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3)),
        'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(), 
        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
        );
        print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_header');
        $this->load->view('announcements',$data);
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_footer');
        //redirect('announcements/index');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array(
        'announcement' => $this->announcement->fetch_announcement($username,$company,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3)),
        'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(), 
        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
        );
        $file_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $result = $this->announcement->create($insert);
        //$this->load->view('includes/admin_header');
        //$this->load->view('announcements',$data);
        //$this->load->view('includes/admin_footer');
        redirect('announcements/index');
    }

}
```

View Code :

```
 <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Added By</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Date Added</th>
    <th>Publish</th>
</tr>
```

```
<?php $offset = $this->uri->segment(3,0)+1; ?>
<?php foreach($announcement as $row): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $offset++; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->addedby; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->company; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->dateadded; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->published; ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
<?php echo $links; ?>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<?php $error = ''; ?>
<h2>Add an announcement</h2>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('announcements/upload'); ?>
<p>Title : <input type="text" name="title"/></p>
<p>Description : 
<textarea style="resize:none;" maxlength="200" row="20" cols="20"     name="description"></textarea>
</p>
<p>Upload file :<input type="file" name="userfile"> </p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
<?php echo $error; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I realized that this creates form resubmit issues as well.

Comment: try this print_r($this->upload->display_errors()); anything appear the error ?

Comment: Yeah it does. An error will appear. However, why doesn't the error that i send from the controller to the view appear? Is there a way to detect it?

Comment: I've changed some code as previously my data variable was being overridden. However the same issues remain.

Comment: okay. print_r($error); in your announcements view file. are you see the same result of display_errors(); ?

Comment: No. nothing prints out for some reason

Comment: are you able to see the announcements view file output in your browser ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100539/discussion-between-jianya-and-vaira-muthu).

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer below code :-

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
```

Ref From : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Let me know, if this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below starting of coding

```
<?php $error = ''; ?>
```

in announcements view file